# How to install a Rust dependency in an environment with no internet?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, tango-controls

I would like to use the [tango client crate](https://docs.rs/tango-client/latest/tango_client/index.html) for a Rust project at work, however the environment that I will be developing this in does not have direct access to the internet.  This means that the standard method of adding the dependency to `Cargo.toml` and running `cargo build` fails due to a network error.

The environment doesn't prevent me from copying data downloaded to an internet-connected computer, and so I was hoping that there would be a way for me to package the necessary files locally, and then point `Cargo.toml` to that location.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Can you connect the environment to the internet once?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-vendor.html maybe?

Comment: you can specify the `path` of a local dependency in `Cargo.toml`, so you might be able to use that to point to a UNC path or something similar on that other machine

Comment: No, sadly I can't connect the machine to the internet, even once.  Cargo vendor looks intriguing.  I'll experiment a bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, thanks to a tip in a comment from @Dogbert.

The trick was to use `cargo vendor` on the machine that has an internet connection.  This will produce a directory called `vendor` that can be transferred to the other environment.  On that environment, and within the directory from which you will run `cargo build`, create a new file in `.cargo/config`.

```
[source]
[source.local_vendor]
directory = "vendor"

[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "local_vendor"
```

Once you've done this, then `cargo build` should work.